# Not able to overwrite old value in Drupal.settings

Tags: 7, ajax, routes, javascript

I am facing Problems in overwriting old value in Drupal.setting.

**Problem Statement**

I am passing FID value from PHP to JS. At first it is getting correct value in JS.

Ex. When PHP is passing FID=59 to JS for first time then it is correctly received by JS.
Next time when it is passing FID=60 then it is showing FID=59 in JS always.
Drupal.setting is not refreshing with current value.

My sample php code is like this

```
 function TraverseSnap($nextFID)
 {
    $thm_slideshowimg .= '<input type="image" src="nxt.jpg" class="clsNextSnap" width="25" height="25">';

    $nxtSnapSetting = array(                
            'fid' => $nextFID,      
     );

    drupal_add_js(array('nxtSnp' => $nxtSnapSetting), 'setting');
 }
```

JS Code

```
(function($) {
 Drupal.behaviors.VidsImgsContent=
 {
      attach: function (context, settings)
      {
          var fileId = Drupal.settings.nxtSnp.fid;
          var dataNextSnap = 'fid=' +fileId;
          $.ajax({
                  url: 'nextsnap',
                  type: 'POST',
                  async : false,                  
                  dataType : 'json',                 
                  data : dataNextSnap,                  
                  success : updateMainNextDiv,
                  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert("Some Error occured");},
                  beforeSend: function()
                  {                        
                  },
               });
               return false;
       }
  }
  })(jQuery);
```

My hook_menu call

```
$items['nextsnap']=array(
   'title'=>t(''),
   'type'=> MENU_CALLBACK,        
   'page callback' => 'nxt_snap_post',       
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

Page Callback

```
function nxt_snap_post()
{               
    $fid=$_POST['fid'];        

    $htmlResult = TraverseSnaps(60); //An arbitary Value for sake of this example
    drupal_json_output($htmlResult);
    exit();
}
```

So I believe when the button is clicked next time it will take FID=60 in JS but it is taking old value instead.

Please help here as my crucial logic depends on this.

Comment: The missing " in your js at line error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert("Some Error occured);}, is just a copy and paste error?

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is just a copy and paste error. I have edited the code now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do it this way. Data Drupal.settings only run in first load. This data store in tag head of page.

[image]

When you call ajax your function was execute, but tag head don't reaload. So Data.settings don't change.

Comment: Then what will be the best way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: do you want create slider with ajax, after click button ajax will loaded and you get file fid for next slider? (sorry my english is not good). You can say what do you want?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I have custom buttons which actually move to next FID on clicking and also load comments regarding those images. Can you help me out? I don't want to try any contributed modules. I want to write PHP & JS code for this.

Comment: I need more info. I want to know structure of image and comment of images. is It content type and comment, and structure of your html slider. Final, i think better you should create new question, say what do you want your slide, and structure of it. I and others will help you better.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have create new question related to this. Please see the link:- [link](
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165086/how-to-create-custom-slider-using-drupalphp-jquery)

Comment: I already see your new question. And see that your problem is just how can derive the value of the next FID. Why do not stores this value into and updated after each button click. Implementing call ajax, ajax complete when you update 2 values in 2 button.

Comment: I didn't get the main point of your comment.Can you please tell again where do you want to store next FID value into?

Comment: This is my way http://tinypic.com/r/zu4n4w/8

Comment: I get your point. But will it be secure to pass sensitive data like FID as part of HTML control? This is because embedding FID in HTML control means anyone can press F12 on firefox browser and get the value by inspecting the button.

Comment: if you data is private, you need process it in server. You can save data to variable global $use. And return html after ajax done.

Comment: Can you please share code example of such kind to get your concept.